# Mysql process list too long with killed queries

Tags: mysql, mariadb, processlist

For several years I've been making automated daily database backups using a procedure iterating over existing databases.

```
mysqldump --user=${mysql_username} --password=${mysql_password} $db --single-transaction --events -R >> $normal_output_filename
```

Recently I moved from a dedicated server (Centos 6, Apache 2.2, php5.6, Mysql 5.0 -as far I recall) to a VPS with Centos 7, Apache 2.4, php 7.2/5.6, MariaDB 5.5)
Recently, time to time SOME database accesses are slow and eventually "time execution exceeded"
I have a cron job to make a daily backup after 03:00 of all databases.
From `ps aux | grep mysql` I get

> root     15840  0.0  0.0 126772  3456 ?        SN   03:09   0:00 mysqldump --user=uuu --password=x xxxxxx information_schema --single-transaction --events -R

which is on hold for several hours.
Once, I realized that problem after six days that mysqldump was on hold and no new db backups were performed.

```
show status like '%conn%';
```

does not output anything, it stays on hold.

```
mysqladmin -uuser1 -p*** processlist
```

(user1 is superuser) lists almost 8000 lines of Killed processes like

```
| 671958 | user1  | localhost | database1 | Killed  | 3 |   |                  | 0.000    |
| 671959 | user1  | localhost | database1 | Killed  | 3 |   |                  | 0.000    |
| 671961 | user1  | localhost | database1 | Killed  | 2 |   |                  | 0.000    |
| 671962 | user1  | localhost | database1 | Killed  | 2 |   |                  | 0.000    |
| 671963 | user1  | localhost | database2 | Killed  | 2 |   |                  | 0.000    |
| 671964 | user2  | localhost | database3 | Killed  | 1 |   |                  | 0.000    |
| 671965 | user1  | localhost |           | Killed  | 1 |   |                  | 0.000    |
| 671966 | user1  | localhost |           | Query   | 0 |   | show processlist | 0.000    |
+--------+-----+--------------+-----------+---------+---+---+------------------+----------+
```

I didn't restart mysql server yet. I can see some websites loading fast their pages which have several db accesses while Horde and Roundcube webmails reach the timeout and error 500.

I don't realize why suddenly (it may be days before it happens) list of processes start growing with killed processes I don't know where they come from.

**UPDATE 1:**
VPS at Contabo, 200GB SSD disk. 61.93 GiB used / 134.78 GiB free / 196.71 GiB total
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz, 4 cores
CentOS Linux 7.7.1908
Linux 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 on x86_64
At this time: CPU load averages 0.88 (1 min) 1.03 (5 mins) 0.95 (15 mins)
8GB RAM - At this time: 1.81 GiB used / 2.21 GiB cached / 7.63 GiB total
At this time: Uptime 2 days, 17 hours

[MORE DATA](https://pastebin.com/YbQw28wX)

**UPDATE 2**

Added `thread_handling=pool-of-threads` to my.cnf

Comment: It is user1 because he has all permissions in all databases

Comment: Is the `user2` a typo or real entry? If real what executes that? Is `$db` = `database1`?

Comment: It is a real entry. It is a user who has privileges on database3

Comment: What does SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%conn%'; reveal?

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck At this time `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%conn%'; ` outputs the same as `show status like '%conn%';`  I intended to post it at the first time but it seems like a second <pre></pre> is not allowed by the editor. AFTER 20 hours restaring mariadb now it is Aborted_connects=18, Connections=360766, Max_used_connections=22, Threads_connected=1. The others (ssl) are =0

Comment: These numbers appear to be reasonable for your very busy system.  Will you have time to post other 'Additional information' requested 10 hours ago for server workload tuning analysis?  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck  Here's the link: https://pastebin.com/YbQw28wX

Comment: Thank you for your available additional information. Analysis will start today.  Hope to have suggestions for you within 24 hours.

Comment: Great!  Thanks.  Should I install `iostat` ?  It is not installed.

Comment: If you could install iostat software, that would be helpful info.  It may reveal the 'shared' VPS is the cause of 'sometimes slow' response time.   From the command line,  iostat -xm 5 3   to gather stats for 5 seconds and 3 cycles - will be done in 20 seconds.

Comment: Ok. I'll add the info the pastebin.com. About the slow db (I guess it is) I only saw it once with Horde webmail. Other times, when the problem appears there are regular db accesses and timeouts (Horde and Roundcube)  Odd. It also was strange that a mysqldump was on hold for 6 days until I realized it because of the main issue.

Comment: Does your VPS host have a list of Global Variables you are either allowed or not allowed to change?  If so, what is the url for their list.  I can see with the iostat report your STEAL factor could be responsible for slow downs in a shared environment.  Could we use Skype to chat for about 10 minutes?  My id is wlhauck@aol.com

Comment: @WilsonHauck You have 2 profiles. I sent you a text at 4:05pm (-3 utc)

Comment: Text to phone or email address or thru Skype chat?  Do not see a message, yet.

Comment: Text to Skype to your email address (Skype for Busin...)

Comment: Can we use regular Skype?

Comment: I see your Skype msg now.

Comment: I've sent you a screenshot of my text to your other Skype profile

Answer (score 1):

The following does not *directly* answer the Question you are asking, but it points out some very low settings and the usage of MyISAM.  I don't know whether switching to InnoDB and/or increasing some of the settings would help.

Do be aware that dumping MyISAM tables essentially blocks users from doing database work.  (On the other hand, perhaps your data set is rather small and the activity is rather low.)

**Observations:**

- Version: 5.5.64-MariaDB
- 8 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 21:05:35; some GLOBAL STATUS values may not be meaningful yet.
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) MyISAM.

**The More Important Issues:**

You should move from MyISAM to InnoDB; see [Conversion from MyISAM to InnoDB](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb)

See if you can raise the following (more discussion below):

```
open_files_limit = 2000
table_open_cache = 300
key_buffer_size = 200M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 600M  -- after moving tables to InnoDB
```

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` is an infrequent task; you are doing it much too often.

**Details and other observations:**

`( (key_buffer_size / 0.20 + innodb_buffer_pool_size / 0.70) ) = ((16M / 0.20 + 128M / 0.70)) / 8192M = 3.2%` -- Most of available ram should be made available for caching.
-- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

`( open_files_limit ) = 760` -- ulimit -n
-- To allow more files, change ulimit or /etc/security/limits.conf or in sysctl.conf (kern.maxfiles & kern.maxfilesperproc) or something else (OS dependent)

`( table_open_cache ) = 64` -- Number of table descriptors to cache
-- Several hundred is usually good.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 128M` -- InnoDB Data + Index cache
-- 128M (an old default) is woefully small.

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 5,578 / 8191 = 68.1%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 134217728) is bigger than necessary?

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( join_buffer_size ) = 131,072 / 8192M = 0.00%` -- 0-N per thread. May speed up JOINs (better to fix queries/indexes) (all engines) Used for index scan, range index scan, full table scan, each full JOIN, etc.
-- If large, decrease join_buffer_size (now 131072) to avoid memory pressure. Suggest less than 1% of RAM. If small, increase to 0.01% of RAM to improve some queries.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_populate ) = OFF = 0` -- NUMA control

`( query_prealloc_size ) = 8,192 / 8192M = 0.00%` -- For parsing. Pct of RAM

`( query_alloc_block_size ) = 8,192 / 8192M = 0.00%` -- For parsing. Pct of RAM

`( character_set_server ) = character_set_server = latin1`
-- Charset problems may be helped by setting character_set_server (now latin1) to utf8mb4. That is the future default.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( Key_writes / Key_write_requests ) = 5,804 / 9232 = 62.9%` -- key_buffer effectiveness for writes
-- If you have enough RAM, it would be worthwhile to increase key_buffer_size (now 16777216).

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Created_tmp_tables ) = 13,250 / 18108 = 73.2%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Maybe increase tmp_table_size (now 16777216) and max_heap_table_size (now 16777216); improve indexes; avoid blobs, etc.

`( (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit ) = (68440 + 1927 + 425 + 0) / 0 = INF` -- Statements per Commit (assuming all InnoDB)
-- Low: Might help to group queries together in transactions; High: long transactions strain various things.

`( Select_scan ) = 165,862 / 75935 = 2.2 /sec` -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Com_optimize ) = 464 / 75935 = 22 /HR` -- How often OPTIMIZE TABLE is performed.
-- OPTIMIZE TABLE is rarely useful, certainly not at high frequency.

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = STATEMENT` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( expire_logs_days ) = 0` -- How soon to automatically purge binlog (after this many days)
-- Too large (or zero) = consumes disk space; too small = need to respond quickly to network/machine crash.
(Not relevant if log_bin (now OFF) = OFF)

`( innodb_autoinc_lock_mode ) = 1` -- Galera: desires 2 -- 2 = "interleaved"; 1 = "consecutive" is typical; 0 = "traditional".
-- Galera desires 2; 2 requires BINLOG_FORMAT=ROW or MIXED

`( log_slow_queries ) = log_slow_queries = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (Before 5.1.29, 5.6.1)

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( back_log ) = 50` -- (Autosized as of 5.6.6; based on max_connections)
-- Raising to min(150, max_connections (now 151)) may help when doing lots of connections.

`( Com_change_db / Connections ) = 1,278,567 / 363881 = 3.51` -- Database switches per connection
-- (minor) Consider using "db.table" syntax

`( Com_change_db ) = 1,278,567 / 75935 = 17 /sec` -- Probably comes from USE statements.
-- Consider connecting with DB, using db.tbl syntax, eliminating spurious USE statements, etc.

`( Threads_running / thread_cache_size ) = 1 / 0 = INF` -- Threads: current / cached (Not relevant when using thread pooling)
-- Optimize queries

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

**Abnormally small:**

```
( Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written ) / Uptime = 0.0672
(innodb_buffer_pool_size + innodb_log_buffer_size + key_buffer_size + query_cache_size + Max_used_connections * (thread_stack + net_buffer_length)) / _ram = 1.9%
Innodb_adaptive_hash_non_hash_searches = 1.1 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed / max(Questions, Queries) = 0.00056
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_young = 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_old = 943
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead = 0
Innodb_checkpoint_max_age = 7.78e+6
Innodb_ibuf_merged_inserts = 0
Innodb_ibuf_merges = 0
Innodb_lsn_current = 2.52e+8
Innodb_lsn_flushed = 240.6MB
Innodb_lsn_last_checkpoint = 2.52e+8
Innodb_master_thread_10_second_loops = 945
Innodb_master_thread_1_second_loops = 10,439
Innodb_master_thread_sleeps = 0.14 /sec
Innodb_mem_adaptive_hash = 2.25e+6
Innodb_mem_dictionary = 2.1e+6
Innodb_mem_total = 131.4MB
Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written = 0.067 /sec
Innodb_x_lock_spin_waits = 0.047 /HR
Open_tables = 64
net_buffer_length = 8,192
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_check = 22 /HR
Com_show_charsets = 28 /HR
Com_show_events = 1.2 /HR
Feature_gis = 0.66 /HR
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
binlog_checksum = NONE
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
opt_s__engine_condition_pushdown = off
opt_s__extended_keys = off
```

Comment: 1) Thanks with your long answer/suggestions. I understand that it is almost impossible to get The Answer, several variables may be involved. I can update Global Vars but I'll have to wait. I restarted mariadb because added `thread_handling=pool-of-threads` to my.cnf as @wilson-hauck suggested by chat. 
99% of db connections are for reading, not for writting. Would be better to change tables to InnoDB? The most accessed db uses 72MB of space. In 1 day and 20 hours of mariadb running Network traffic was 16.1GB (most by msn, google and moz bots)

Comment: @dstonek - InnoDB is preferred for performance, crash recovery, etc, etc.  One downside: The disk footprint is 2-3 times as much as for MyISAM.

Comment: So because of memory allocation changes ALL tables should be altered. Despite I have backups I guess it would be better to duplicate databases, lock, alter tables in one of them, check and finally delete the old one.

Comment: @dstonek - The alternative is to gradually decrease `key_buffer_size` and increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` as you change tables.  Other conversion tips: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: I have FULLTEXT keys. It seems they are supported in version 5.6

Comment: @dstonek - Yes.  A different implementation of `FULLTEXT` was added to 5.6's InnoDB.  I mention some of the differences in that blog.

Comment: But my mariadb version is 5.5 so full text searches are not possible with innodb, isn’t it?

Comment: @dstonek - 5.5 is quite old.  Anyway, you could leave the FT tables in MyISAM while migrating the other tables to InnoDB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206195/discussion-between-dstonek-and-rick-james).

Comment: I've changed almost all tables to InnoDB engine but those with FULLTEXTs.  After 5 days of mariaDB service running this is a data collection https://pastebin.com/yTpVbuA2 `open_files_limit` new value is not reflected yet, some as others.

Answer (score 1):

Some things have changed...

**Observations:**

- Version: 5.5.64-MariaDB
- 8 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 5d 15:01:27
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- It appears that you are running both MyISAM and InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

For 8GB and a mixture of MyISAM and InnoDB:

```
key_buffer_size = 800M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3000M
```

`ulimit -n` is 1024.  Yet `open_files_limit` is only 760.  I don't know how to get those raised and keep them raised.

innodb_log_file_size = 5M -- This is too low.  However, it will be messy to change.

24 OPTIMIZEs/hour is very high, even for MyISAM.  1/month might be more realistic.

There are indications of slow queries; see my blog for how to chase that.

thread_cache_size -- set to 30; this may significantly speed up connections.

**Details and other observations:**

[Conversion from MyISAM to InnoDB](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb)

`( (key_buffer_size / 0.20 + innodb_buffer_pool_size / 0.70) ) = ((200M / 0.20 + 128M / 0.70)) / 8192M = 14.4%` -- Most of available ram should be made available for caching.
-- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

`( open_files_limit ) = 760` -- ulimit -n
-- To allow more files, change ulimit or /etc/security/limits.conf or in sysctl.conf (kern.maxfiles & kern.maxfilesperproc) or something else (OS dependent)

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 128M` -- InnoDB Data + Index cache
-- 128M (an old default) is woefully small.

`( innodb_log_buffer_size / innodb_log_file_size ) = 8M / 5M = 160.0%` -- Buffer is in RAM; file is on disk.
-- The buffer_size should be smaller and/or the file_size should be larger.

`( innodb_flush_method ) = innodb_flush_method =` -- How InnoDB should ask the OS to write blocks. Suggest O_DIRECT or O_ALL_DIRECT (Percona) to avoid double buffering. (At least for Unix.) See chrischandler for caveat about O_ALL_DIRECT

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor.

`( innodb_stats_on_metadata ) = innodb_stats_on_metadata = ON` -- Re-analyze table when touching stats.
-- ON is likely to slow down certain SHOWs and information_schema accesses.

`( innodb_recovery_update_relay_log ) = innodb_recovery_update_relay_log = OFF` -- Helps avoid replication errors after a crash.

`( innodb_import_table_from_xtrabackup ) = 0` -- Useful for transportable tablespaces

`( sync_binlog ) = 0` -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( character_set_server ) = character_set_server = latin1`
-- Charset problems may be helped by setting character_set_server (now latin1) to utf8mb4. That is the future default.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Created_tmp_tables ) = 98,045 / 181066 = 54.1%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Maybe increase tmp_table_size (now 16777216) and max_heap_table_size (now 16777216); improve indexes; avoid blobs, etc.

`( (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit ) = (388211 + 19570 + 3890 + 330) / 0 = INF` -- Statements per Commit (assuming all InnoDB)
-- Low: Might help to group queries together in transactions; High: long transactions strain various things.

`( Select_scan ) = 945,274 / 486087 = 1.9 /sec` -- full table scans 
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Com_optimize ) = 3,202 / 486087 = 24 /HR` -- How often OPTIMIZE TABLE is performed.
-- OPTIMIZE TABLE is rarely useful, certainly not at high frequency.

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = STATEMENT` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( expire_logs_days ) = 0` -- How soon to automatically purge binlog (after this many days)
-- Too large (or zero) = consumes disk space; too small = need to respond quickly to network/machine crash.
(Not relevant if log_bin (now OFF) = OFF)

`( log_slow_queries ) = log_slow_queries = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (Before 5.1.29, 5.6.1)

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query. 
-- Suggest 2

`( back_log ) = 50` -- (Autosized as of 5.6.6; based on max_connections) 
-- Raising to min(150, max_connections (now 151)) may help when doing lots of connections.

`( Com_change_db / Connections ) = 8,920,272 / 2392646 = 3.73` -- Database switches per connection 
-- (minor) Consider using "db.table" syntax

`( Com_change_db ) = 8,920,272 / 486087 = 18 /sec` -- Probably comes from USE statements.
-- Consider connecting with DB, using db.tbl syntax, eliminating spurious USE statements, etc.

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

**Abnormally small:**

```
Innodb_adaptive_hash_non_hash_searches = 46 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data = 272 /sec
Innodb_checkpoint_max_age = 7.78e+6
Innodb_master_thread_10_second_loops = 17,345
Innodb_master_thread_1_second_loops = 184,979
Innodb_master_thread_sleeps = 0.38 /sec
Innodb_mem_adaptive_hash = 4.17e+6
Innodb_mem_dictionary = 4.15e+6
Innodb_mem_total = 131.4MB
net_buffer_length = 8,192
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_check = 24 /HR
Com_create_db = 0.15 /HR
Com_drop_db = 0.044 /HR
Com_rename_table = 0.49 /HR
Com_show_charsets = 16 /HR
Com_show_events = 17 /HR
Com_show_storage_engines = 1.9 /HR
Feature_gis = 1.1 /HR
Feature_locale = 20 /HR
Threadpool_idle_threads = 7
Threadpool_threads = 8
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
binlog_checksum = NONE
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
opt_s__engine_condition_pushdown = off
opt_s__extended_keys = off
thread_handling = pool-of-threads
```

Comment: About `open_file_limits` I don't know where it is set as 760. I've set `ulimit -n 2048` (twice)  but for an unknown reason it turns to 1024 (could be VPS settings?) I also created /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/limits.conf  `[Service] 
LimitNOFILE=2048`, then `systemctl daemon-reload` and recently `systemctl restart mariadb`

Comment: "Optimize" moved to cron.monthly. After an hour slow queries log is empty with long_query_time=.5 During 1/2 hour and reducing to .2 I got one 0.206sec query which used MyISAM engine (FT). I also have reduced connections to the most accessed db. Answer from Contabo VPS about global var limits: "As you have full root rights on your VPS S SSD (173.x.x.x) any configurations are in your capable hands. There should not be any such limit.

Comment: After changing all possible engines to Innodb (remaining MyISAM have lot of mysql activity), reduced mysql accesses and changing few settings, RAM is being increased from "real" 30% to 45% average (from Webmin Panel) Data include sar comparison https://pastebin.com/L4GyxnfN